# i want prevent double clicked event at tree control in MFC?

Tags: mfc

i have implemented multi selection when LButtonDown from tree control in  MFC

but when i do fast click repeatedly Mouse LButtonDown then a problem arises.

i thinks this problem is occoured by double clicked event when i  clicked fast

repeadtly.

i want to acquired click event only except double clickevent.

importance is must be solved this problem in only  LBUTTONDOWN event and  LButtonClick event.

please help me. ~
my english writing is so badddest. sorry.

below is my source's part.

```
  void CFileTreeCtrl::OnLButtonDown(UINT nFlags , CPoint point)
  {

    //LRESULT *pResult = 0;

    GetCursorPos(&point);
    ::ScreenToClient(this->m_hWnd, &point);

    HTREEITEM hItem = this->HitTest(point, &nFlags);

    // if items is exist and event is occured
   if (hItem != NULL && (nFlags & TVHT_ONITEMSTATEICON) != 0)
   {
    // if items is checked
    if (this->GetCheck(hItem))
    {
        UnCheckChildItems(hItem);
    }
    // items is not checked
    else
    {
        CheckChildItems(hItem);
    }
  }

   CDragDropTreeCtrl::OnLButtonDown(nFlags, point);
 }

//=========================================================
// checked all child items
//========================================================= 

void CFileTreeCtrl::CheckChildItems(HTREEITEM hItem)
{
  HTREEITEM hChildItem = this->GetChildItem(hItem);

  while (hChildItem != NULL)
  {
    this->SetCheck(hChildItem, TRUE);

    if (this->ItemHasChildren(hChildItem))
    {
        CheckChildItems(hChildItem);
    }

    hChildItem = this->GetNextItem(hChildItem, TVGN_NEXT);
 } 
}


 //=========================================================
 // Uncheck all child items.
//=========================================================

 void CFileTreeCtrl::UnCheckChildItems(HTREEITEM hItem)
 {
   HTREEITEM hChildItem = this->GetChildItem(hItem);

   while (hChildItem != NULL)
  {
    this->SetCheck(hChildItem, FALSE);

    if (this->ItemHasChildren(hChildItem))
    {
        UnCheckChildItems(hChildItem);
    }

    hChildItem = this->GetNextItem(hChildItem, TVGN_NEXT);
  }
 }
```

Comment: You write _"when I do fast click repeatedly Mouse LButtonDown then a problem arises"_. But __which__ problem arises?

Comment: i have clicked  repeatedly fast  then  not working checkd well , i have thinked that problem  is because of double click event is occurred .

Comment: check and uncheck action is  ignored when i  clicked fast repeatedly. but click slower is work very well.

Comment: You don't search in the good direction. Your problem is not the fast double clicking but the action wich will be done when your selection changed. Add this to see what happend  `ON_NOTIFY(LVN_ITEMCHANGED, IDC_CTRL, OnItemchangedList)`

Comment: thank you all , i have solved today *^^* , my mistake is that  processing in LBUTTON_DOWN event ,  now i implementation  like this : ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT(NM_CLICK , OnNMClickTreeDevices)  , now working well ~